# Kubernetes ConfigMap directory permissions

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I want to configure elasticsearch with the elasticsearch.yml, located in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config. I am doing this via a ConfigMap which I mount into the container.

That does not work due to k8s takes over the control of this directory and the other files of that directory does not exist anymore (eg jvm.options).

I think that is a common issue - is there a best practice to fix this? The first idea which came to my mind was symlinking to /some/other/directory/elasticsearch.yml with an initcontainer. Is that wise to do so?

Answer (score 1):

So found a proper solution I want to share with you. The magic happens with the subPath in the volumeMount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
...
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    containers:
      ...
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config
        mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        subPath: elasticsearch.yml
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: elasticsearch-logging
```